# Python Converting i18n resource strings into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I work in localization and as a part of my job we have English resource files translated into multiple languages. As you can see in the crude example below the files contain multiple lines (copyright, disclaimers, comments, ect) I need to convert only the lines containing `=` to dictionary key/value pairs. Here is an example:

```
Copyright 2015
resource files for product 'XYZ'

#resource files for backend
String_id_1 = This should be import<br>
String_id_2 = This is another import string<br>
String_id_3 = Another string bla bla

#resource files for plug-in X
String_id_4 = This should be import<br>
String_id_5 = This is another import string<br>
String_id_6 = Another string bla bla
```

The purpose of this is to provide a safeguard for my check-ins to compare the keys of EN and other locales for continuity.

Comment: So have you tried to solve this yourself yet? What problems did you encounter when you tried?

Comment: All you need to do is look for `=` in a line, ensure that the line doesn't start with `#` then use `str.split()` or `str.partition()` to get key-value pairs to add to a dictionary..